# Google Sheets API v4 Error: 'Invalid requests[0].addFilterView: No grid with id: 2'

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-sheets-api

Adding a filter view through Google Sheets API v4. I've checked many different SO posts and other resources, and I just cant find an explanation that matches my situation.

I've quadruple checked these spreadsheets and they all have sheets that have a sheetId of 2. I've ran the code on multiple different files and have gotten this error. When I ran the code on some of the files using sheetId: 0, I would get the same error message `'Invalid requests[0].addFilterView: No grid with id: 0'`

Here is the code:

My actual production spreadsheet

```
const request = {
        spreadsheetId: '1qWoAjFHik5oJ8_hXTatEgVj5sVExxQWxgFVCM_uHwXE',
        resource: {
            requests: [{
                "addFilterView": {
                    filter: {
                        filterViewId: 11,
                        title: 'Claims Without A Status',
                        range: {
                            sheetId: 2,
                            startRowIndex: 0,
                            endRowIndex: 50,
                            startColumnIndex: 0,
                            endColumnIndex: 3
                        },
                        filterSpecs: [
                            {
                                filterCriteria: {
                                    condition: {
                                        type: 'BLANK',
                                        values: []
                                    }
                                },
                                columnIndex: 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }

    sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This produces:

```
errors: [
    {
      message: 'Invalid requests[0].addFilterView: No grid with id: 2',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ]
```

A test I ran on another sheet:

```
const request = {
        spreadsheetId: '1Fnu1s2DEZaSIX94rJug2sbmeseHO7tQ_M9nJX4rvPHE',
        resource: {
            requests: [{
                "addFilterView": {
                    filter: {
                        filterViewId: 11,
                        title: 'Claims Without A Status',
                        range: {
                            sheetId: 2,
                            startRowIndex: 0,
                            endRowIndex: 50,
                            startColumnIndex: 0,
                            endColumnIndex: 3
                        },
                        filterSpecs: [
                            {
                                filterCriteria: {
                                    condition: {
                                        type: 'BLANK',
                                        values: []
                                    }
                                },
                                columnIndex: 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }

    sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Produced:

```
[
    {
      message: 'Invalid requests[0].addFilterView: No grid with id: 2',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ]
```

BUT this code actually worked:

```
const request = {
        spreadsheetId: '1Fnu1s2DEZaSIX94rJug2sbmeseHO7tQ_M9nJX4rvPHE',
        resource: {
            requests: [{
                "addFilterView": {
                    filter: {
                        filterViewId: 12,
                        title: 'Claims Without A Status',
                        range: {
                            sheetId: 0,
                            startRowIndex: 0,
                            endRowIndex: 50,
                            startColumnIndex: 0,
                            endColumnIndex: 3
                        },
                        filterSpecs: [
                            {
                                filterCriteria: {
                                    condition: {
                                        type: 'BLANK',
                                        values: []
                                    }
                                },
                                columnIndex: 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }

    sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Produced:

```
status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  request: {
    responseURL: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1Fnu1s2DEZaSIX94rJug2sbmeseHO7tQ_M9nJX4rvPHE:batchUpdate'
  }
```

So, I figured, something with the second index, despite the fact that both sheets have at least 6 sheets in them (which would mean there will always be a sheet with index/id of 2, right?). So, I tried running the sheetId: 0 code with my production sheet. The code:

```
const request = {
        spreadsheetId: '1qWoAjFHik5oJ8_hXTatEgVj5sVExxQWxgFVCM_uHwXE',
        resource: {
            requests: [{
                "addFilterView": {
                    filter: {
                        filterViewId: 12,
                        title: 'Claims Without A Status',
                        range: {
                            sheetId: 0,
                            startRowIndex: 0,
                            endRowIndex: 50,
                            startColumnIndex: 0,
                            endColumnIndex: 3
                        },
                        filterSpecs: [
                            {
                                filterCriteria: {
                                    condition: {
                                        type: 'BLANK',
                                        values: []
                                    }
                                },
                                columnIndex: 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }

    sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Produced:

```
errors: [
    {
      message: 'Invalid requests[0].addFilterView: No grid with id: 0',
      domain: 'global',
      reason: 'badRequest'
    }
  ]
```

So, I'm getting conflicting responses from different spreadsheets, even when the circumstances are the same. For any spreadsheet to even exist it has to have one sheet, which means there will ALWAYS be a sheet at index/id 0.

**EDIT**

I attempted to try this on two different spreadsheets: An old spreadsheet I've been using and another test spreadsheet that I just created. The api call failed with the same message for the old spreadsheet but the api call worked for the new spreadsheet just like the one above.

This could boil down to sheetIds being statically assigned at inception. If you create a couple of sheets, delete a couple, and then create more, the sheet number will increment to the previous highest value, the last sheet, even if you deleted those other sheets. So, for example, if you have Sheet1 Sheet2 and Sheet3, if you delete Sheet3 and create another sheet, the next sheet will be Sheet4 and you'll be with Sheet1 Sheet2 Sheet4. This leads me to believe something similar could be happening in my older files. I've deleted and created a lot of sheets in those old ones.

**EDIT 2**

I tried to add a new sheet to the test sheet and apply the filter view to sheetId 1, but I got the error message but saying `No grid with id: 1`. I can't possibly imagine what is going on here. It seems like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The sheetId needs to be the sheetId from the sheets properties, not the index of the sheet in the sheets list. The official documentation says otherwise though and it is misleading. But, I found the sheetId for one of my sheets and ran the code successfully. Here is what the successful code looks like:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'token.json';

fs.readFile('credentials.json', (err, content) => {
  if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  authorize(JSON.parse(content), listMajors);
});

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    callback(oAuth2Client);
  });
}

function getNewToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return console.error('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) return console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

async function listMajors(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});

    const allSheets = await sheets
        .spreadsheets
            .get({ spreadsheetId: '1qWoAjFHik5oJ8_hXTatEgVj5sVExxQWxgFVCM_uHwXE' })

    const sheetIndicies = {
        Audit: null,
        Billing: null,
        Closed: null
    }

    const sheetInfoArr = []

    allSheets.data.sheets.forEach(sheet => {
        if (sheet.properties.title === 'Audit' || sheet.properties.title === 'Billing' || sheet.properties.title === 'Closed') {
            sheetIndicies[sheet.properties.title] = sheet.properties.sheetId

            const { properties } = sheet
            const { gridProperties } = properties

            sheetInfoArr.push({
                sheetId: properties.index,
                startRowIndex: 0,
                endRowIndex: gridProperties.rowCount,
                startColumnIndex: 0,
                endColumnIndex: gridProperties.columnCount,
                name: sheet.properties.title
            })
        }
    })

    const request = {
        spreadsheetId: '1qWoAjFHik5oJ8_hXTatEgVj5sVExxQWxgFVCM_uHwXE',
        resource: {
            requests: [{
                "addFilterView": {
                    filter: {
                        filterViewId: 33,
                        title: 'Claims Without A Status 33',
                        range: {
                            sheetId: 513982100,
                            startRowIndex: 0,
                            endRowIndex: 50,
                            startColumnIndex: 0,
                            endColumnIndex: 3
                        },
                        filterSpecs: [
                            {
                                filterCriteria: {
                                    condition: {
                                        type: 'BLANK',
                                        values: []
                                    }
                                },
                                columnIndex: 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }

    sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate(request).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Lines 65-80 (the allSheetsData.forEach) were used to gather the sheetIds and put them in an object with the sheets name being the key. I'll be using this array to loop through the sheets I want and I'll pprogrammatically set the row and column indexes to the sheets dimensions. I haven't implemented this yet though because of the error I run into. If I update the code and run back into another issue, I'll post.

Comment: Thanks so much for solving this.  Using your insight I also found that I can take the URL parameter "gid=xxxxxxxx" and use that for the sheetId and it works.  I will try to update the documentation.